# Updating MySql Column based on another Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I am still pretty new to MySQL and I just ran into a problem that I can't seem to figure out.

Say I have a table called "tracks" with the following columns and sample data

```
track_hash | track_order 
abc        | 1
abc        | 2
abc        | 3
abc        | 4
def        | 1
def        | 2
ghi        | 1
```

So the point is that when I display the tracks, the tracks should be ordered by the track order. So if i want to display all tracks from abc, it will display it based on the track order (1, 2, 3). Track hash "def" has two tracks...etc.

So currently in my DB I just have an empty track_order column. How would I go about to filling the track_order column with the correct data?

Comment: so you want each hash to have a consecutive track_order from 1 to N? There's no apparent reason to order them and no criteria for that either

Comment: Do you mean through php or just mysql? Are you looking for a one time thing, or do you always want track order?

Comment: @Bono Doing it through just mysql. I already have a DB set up with a lot of different track information. Some tracks are hashed together and I will figure out the php code to alter the track order value later on. I just need to get the track order column set up first

Comment: @amenadiel Ya sorry about that I realized I should have put more into my example. My track table has a lot of other information such as track name...track audio...track artist...etc. When it is displayed to the webpage, I want users to be able to rearrange the order in which the tracks are displayed. That's why I wanted to add the track order column

Comment: Does the track order matter for now, or is an incremental of one for each track_hash enough for now?

Comment: @Bono Incremental is enough for now!

Comment: @DavidYuan You solved your problem? If you solved don't forget check a answer as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `update` and a user defined variable.  However, you have a fundamental problem.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  So, there is no inherent ordering in the table, unless a column specifies the order.

Let me assume there is a column called `id`.  Then the following does what you want:

```
update tracks t
    set t.track_order = if(@th = t.track_hash, (@rn := coalesce(@rn, 0) + 1),
                           if(@th := t.track_hash, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
                          )
    order by t.track_hash, t.id;
```

You don't have to initialize the variables for this to work, but you can initialize them before the `update`.

Comment: The problem with this is that you are never setting "@th" to the updated track_hash...This will just fill my whole table with 1

Comment: @DavidYuan . . . The second clause of the `if` sets `@th`.  On the first iteration, the first `if()` will fail and it will then be set to the correct value.

Comment: I just tried this an it set my whole column to 1's. From my understanding...

the first iteration will go to the second if statement but the second if statement will only set @rn = 1?

Comment: wait sorry I made a typo. This works perfectly. Thank you so much! I misread the := operator in the second if for just =

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

You could do something like this:

```
SET @t1=0; 
insert into `tablename` (track_order) values(@t1 := @t1+1) where id = some_id
```

I'm not entirely sure how you would go about doing it for every record in your database. I think this should work, but this does it on a per `id` basis (you could make it `track_hash` if that would be better). Not sure if that suits you?

You'll have to do it manually for every `track_hash` this way, so if you have a lot of different `track_hash` records it might be worth figuring out how to do it for all of them in one go. But I'm unsure of how to do that.

Comment: I am having the same problem figuring out a way to do it for every track_hash. Your way solves the problem of being able to update one whole track_hash at the same time but currently I have about 8000+ different track_hashes in my database :(

Comment: Quick question; do you have something of an id column? You could do it the same way if it was all incremental ids.

Comment: Yes I do. Again my problem wasn't the incrementing. It's the fact that I have to reset my variable everytime here is a new track_hash. I understand what I have to do and everything it's just that I'm pretty unfamiliar with the sql syntax